# How to mask or hide sensitive values in serialized JSON objects in a longer string using log4net

Tags: json, asp.net-core, security, logging, log4net

As part of a task, I had to mask sensitive values of properties that contain passwords, etc. during logging and do it in a way that doesn't change the calling code.

For example, in a client in the ASP.NET Core project, the calling code looked like this:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
RequestDto dto = new RequestDto();
dto.Body = new RequestDtoBody();
dto.Body.pwd = "12345";
// Fill all the necessary properties to make the request...

logger.Debug("Making request: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto)); //...
```

The value for property `pwd` should be replaced with `***` but the logger only receives a message that is a string.

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of research and experimentation hours, I was able to make a solution by extending LayoutSkeleton and reforming the message like so:

```
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Layout;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Company.Project.Logging
{
    public class MaskLayout : LayoutSkeleton
    {
        private string _search;

        public string Search
        {
            get { return _search; }
            set { _search = value; }
        }

        private string _mask;

        public string Mask
        {
            get { return _mask; }
            set { _mask = value; }
        }

        public MaskLayout()
        {
            IgnoresException = true;
        }

        public override void ActivateOptions()
        {
        }

        public override void Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (loggingEvent == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");
            }

            // We receive a string which potentially has JSON object(s) inside that need to be checked.
            var message = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage;
            if (message == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var search = _search.Split(new char[] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // Consecutive number of a JSON object openings always match number of closings.
            // This makes it easier to check if there are valid JSONs in the message.
            char[] openings = { '{', '[' };
            char[] closings = { ']', '}' };
            int stack = 0;
            bool dirty = false;
            var reg = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
            {
                var @char = message[i];

                if (openings.Contains(@char))
                {
                    dirty = true;
                    ++stack;
                }
                else if (dirty && closings.Contains(@char))
                    --stack;

                if (dirty)
                {
                    reg.Append(@char);
                    if (stack == 0)
                    {
                        // Check JSON
                        try
                        {
                            var json = JObject.Parse(Regex.Unescape(reg.ToString()));
                            foreach (var jToken in json.DescendantsAndSelf())
                            {
                                if (jToken is JObject obj)
                                    foreach (var prop in obj.Properties())
                                        if (prop.Value is not JObject && prop.Value is not JArray)
                                            if (search.Contains(prop.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                                prop.Value = _mask;
                            }

                            // Convert the edited JSON back to string and write it to the stream.
                            writer.Write(json.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // Invalid JSON, dump reg on stream
                            writer.Write(reg);
                        }

                        dirty = false;
                        reg.Clear();
                    }
                }
                else
                    writer.Write(@char); // no JSON
            }

            if (dirty)
                writer.Write(reg);

            reg.Clear();

            writer.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The code probes for JSON objects by checking the number of openings and closings that must match for the JSON object to be valid. As long as the current character in the logged message is not building a JSON, it's written instantly on the stream. Otherwise, a StringBuilder is used to hold the characters that could be a JSON and when it completes, it is temporarily converted to a JObject which in turn is traversed to mask (replace) or hide all the values for the sensitive properties.

This custom layout can be used where log4net is configured like so:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\log2.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="Company.Project.Logging.MaskLayout">
        <search value="password,pwd" />
        <mask value="***" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Virtually all logging frameworks should support implementing interceptors such as the one discussed. I hope this saves some people time.